# Iterate through big list and edit all list items without causing a lot of lag?

Tags: c#

I'm iterating through a big list filled with rectangles and every frame they should go downby 1 pixel but due to the massive amount of rectangles I'm getting a huge fps drop my code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < Water3.Count(); x++ )
{
    bool intersect = false;
    Rectangle rect = Water3[x];
    List<Rectangle> Water2 = new List<Rectangle>(Water3);
    Water2.RemoveAt(x);
    rect.Y++;
    foreach (Rectangle check in Water2)
    {
        if (check.IntersectsWith(rect))
        {
            intersect = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (rect.Y >= 699 || intersect == true)
    {
        rect.Y--;
    }
    Water[x] = rect;
    frameGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), Water3[x]);
}
```

This is my code as for now:

```
private void render()
{
    int framesRendered = 0;
    long startTime = Environment.TickCount;

    Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(Game.CANVAS_WIDTH, Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    Graphics frameGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(frame);


    #region Brushes

    SolidBrush Black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    SolidBrush Red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    #endregion 

    while (true)
    {
        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(Black, 0, 0, Game.CANVAS_WIDTH, Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        List<Rectangle> Water3 = new List<Rectangle>(Water);

        for (var x = 0; x < Water3.Count; x++)
        {
            Rectangle rect = Water3[x];
            rect.Y++;

            bool intersect = Water3.Where((t, i) => i != x).Any(check => check.IntersectsWith(rect));

            if (rect.Y >= 699 || intersect)
                rect.Y--;

            Water[x] = rect;
            frameGraphics.FillRectangle(Red, Water3[x]);
        }

        drawHandle.DrawImage(frame, 0, 0);

        //benchmarking
        framesRendered++;
        if (Environment.TickCount >= startTime + 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Engine: " + framesRendered + " fps");
            framesRendered = 0;
            startTime = Environment.TickCount;
```

Comment: If `Water3` is a list then use `.Count` property instead of `.Count()`

Comment: Changed .count() to .count but i'm still getting a huge fps drop tho.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the list again and again in your loop:

```
List<Rectangle> Water2 = new List<Rectangle>(Water3);
```

That will give you a massive n^2 perf hit.

Comment: How would I fix this? because I need to recreate those lists everytime.

Comment: You don't need to recreate Water2 every single iteration. You are not using it anywhere outside. So to start instead of copying the list, just iterate over Water3 (using for rather than foreach), and if index matches don't try to compare. Still this algorithm is pretty inefficient (n^2), you can pre sort your Water3, and only search in the range where matches are possible (example rect.X to rect.X + Width, then stop)

Answer (score 0):

As Yishai already said, you are creating a huge list Water3 in each loop. That's allocating and deallocating a lot of memory in each cycle which has a huge performance impact. So better work with the lists that you already have.

```
        for (var x = 0; x < Water3.Count; x++)
        {
            bool intersect = false;
            Rectangle rect = Water3[x];
            rect.Y++;

            for (var i = 0; i < Water3.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == x)
                    continue;

                Rectangle check = Water3[i];
                if (check.IntersectsWith(rect))
                {
                    intersect = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (rect.Y >= 699 || intersect)
                rect.Y--;

            Water[x] = rect;
            // painting 1000 rects like this takes about 12msec
            // frameGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);
        }

        // painting all 1000 rects at once will take only 3msec
        frameGraphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.Red, Water.ToArray());
```

Or go with a LINQ expression:

```
        for (var x = 0; x < Water3.Count; x++)
        {
            Rectangle rect = Water3[x];
            rect.Y++;

            bool intersect = Water3.Where((t, i) => i != x).Any(check => check.IntersectsWith(rect));

            if (rect.Y >= 699 || intersect)
                rect.Y--;

            Water[x] = rect;

            // painting 1000 rects like this takes about 12msec
            // frameGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);
        }

        // painting all 1000 rects at once will take only 3msec
        frameGraphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.Red, Water.ToArray());
```

Another comment regarding memory leaks. You should not create a SolidBrush over and over again in the loop. But rather create the brush outside the loop and put it into a using-statement so that it gets disposed afterwards. And if you need a typical color - like you: red - then don't create your own brush but use the static member Brushes.Red instead.

Comment: Both of those are still giving me huge fps drops Image: (http://i.imgur.com/swBFQjG.png) each dot representing a rectangle in my list.

Comment: Did you try drawing many rectangles without modifying them? My guess is that GDI+ (...FillRectangle) is simply too slow for so many objects.

Comment: Looks like your painting is still rather expensive.
Can you separate painting from calculating of what to paint? Also do you need to Fill the rectangle on every frame? If most of them don't change, just paint the ones that did change. Another small thing, create the solidbrush once outside the loop.

Comment: Updated code but still lagging alot i think its this line: 
                frameGraphics.FillRectangle(Black, 0, 0, Game.CANVAS_WIDTH, Game.CANVAS_HEIGHT);

Comment: You can't paint just the rectangles that have changed because the complete canvas gets invalidated, so you need to paint everything. The key point is to send all rectangles for painting at once. For example: if you draw each rectangle separately (let's say 1000 rects) it will take 12msec. If you use FillRectangles, it takes only 3msec!